# how to random select row in one table according to each row in other table?

Tags: mysql, sql

there are 2 tables:

`crash` and `traffic_flow`.

`crash` table has attributes as `crash_date`, `time`, and corresponding detector `ID`.

`traffic_flow` table recorded by detectors has attributes `date`,`time`,`detector_ID`, auto-incrementing id and traffic flow parameters.

Now I'm willing to random select 10 rows in `traffic_flow` for each row in crash respectively and insert them in a new table.

The following is a trial:

```
select traffic_flow.id
from traffic_flow,crash
where traffic_flow.date=crash.date and traffic_flow.ID=crash.ID
order by rand()
limit 10;
```

but this sql statement select 10 rows in total for all crash records, not for each row in crash, so it can't meet my requirement. could you please modify the statement for me?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - formatted text, not images. (Tip: 3 is less than 10, but still same problem.)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, the simplest method is to use variables to enumerate the rows for each crash:

```
select *
from (select ct.*,
             (@rn := if(@ct = id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@ct := id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (select c.*, tf.id as tf_id
            from traffic_flow tf join
                 crash c
                 on tf.date = c.date and tf.ID = c.ID
            order by c.id, rand()
           ) ct cross join
           (select @cid := -1, @rn := 0) params
     )
where rn <= 10;
```